# Convert gitlab-ci artifact job into Jenkins post section

Tags: jenkins

This should be easy, but I cannot figure out the equivalent in Jenkins. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I am new to Jenkins and trying to convert my GitLab-ci job into a Jenkins pipeline.

````
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./mvnw clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE -Dspock.configuration=src/test/groovy/com/pet/api/test/runners/UnitTestsConfig.groovy
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/surefire-reports
      - target/site/jacoco
    expire_in: 30 days
    reports:
      junit:
        - target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
    ```

Currently, I have translated it to be Jenkins stage:
````

````
   stage("Unit Tests") {
      steps {
        sh './mvnw clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE -Dspock.configuration=src/test/groovy/com/pet/api/test/runners/UnitTestsConfig.groovy'
      }
      post {
        always {
          junit 'target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        }
      }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [archive Artifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#archive-archive-artifacts) basic step. Here is a snippet of pipeline job where I do this in the post section of the pipeline. Be aware that the right side uses an [Ant style pattern](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

```
post {
    cleanup {
      archiveArtifacts '**/*.log'
      cleanWs(
    }
}
```